# Assigning data to struct variable gives compiler error: storage size of ‘localAddress’ isn’t known

Tags: c, struct

When trying to assign data to a struct variable, I get this compiler error: error: storage size of ‘localAddress’ isn’t known. Since it's all in the same file, the compiler should know the storage size. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    struct address localAddress;
    localAddress.streetNum = 123;
    localAddress.streetName = "Saxony ct.";
    localAddress.city = "New York";
    localAddress.state = "New York";
    localAddress.zip = 1000;
    return 0;
}

struct address {
    int streetNum;
    char streetName[30];
    char city[30];
    char state[2];
    int zip;
};
```

Comment: Move the struct definition so it is before `main`

Comment: You have to declare the struct before you use it. Move it above the main function.

Comment: Furthermore, this: `localAddress.streetName = "Saxony ct.";` doesn't work anyway, you had to `strcpy()` it.

Comment: `if(fruit.lowhanging() && answer.isfound(beginner.book) && question.isduplicate()) { answer.post(anyway); } #if 0 vote.close(SIMPLE_TYPO); #endif`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the declaration of the `struct` first and then the main function. Also, those string assignments won't work, you need `strcpy` instead:

```
strcpy(localAddress.streetName, "Saxony ct.");
strcpy(localAddress.city, "New York");
strcpy(localAddress.state, "New York");
```

And of course, `char state[2];` isn't big enough to hold that, maybe you also wanted it to be size `30`? Another way of doing it is just using pointers instead in the `struct` definition, then you can assign it like you have it:

```
char *streetName;
char *city;
char *state;
```

Note that this isn't doing the same same thing though, so you can change the actual strings afterwards. If you need to actually store the string in your data structure, you'll have to work with `strcpy`.

Comment: I had actually meant for the state to be a 2 letter code, I just typed the full name in instead of NY. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. For a two letter code you need size `3` though because it's also going to copy the null terminator that's at the end of a string.

Answer (score 1):

At the point where the declaration of `localAddress` appears, no definition of type `struct address` is in scope.  The compiler therefore does not know how large a `struct address` is, nor either how to interpret the accesses to its members.  This situation is invalid.

The scope of the definition appearing later in the file starts at its closing brace.  The usual C idiom is to place type definitions such as that near the top of source files, possibly in headers included from near the top, so that those definitions are visible in all functions defined in that source file.

Answer (score 1):

You must move the definition of `struct` address to above the declaration of `localAddress` to do away with that particular error message:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    struct address {
        int streetNum;
        char streetName[30];
        char city[30];
        char state[2];
        int zip;
    };

    struct address localAddress;
    localAddress.streetNum = 123;
    localAddress.streetName = "Saxony ct.";
    localAddress.city = "New York";
    localAddress.state = "New York";
    localAddress.zip = 1000;
    return 0;
}
```

Still, this does not eliminate all errors in your code. Attempting to compile this code yeilds the following error(s):

> main.c:71:33: error: assignment to expression with array type
>            localAddress.streetName = "Saxony ct.";
>                                    ^
>   main.c:72:27: error: assignment to expression with array type
>            localAddress.city = "New York";
>                              ^
>   main.c:73:28: error: assignment to expression with array type
>            localAddress.state = "New York";

You cannot assign to arrays in that manner. You must use a function like `strcpy()` for this purpose:

```
strcpy(localAddress.city, "New York");
...
```